# Capture URL Parameters in SAML Response

Tags: spring-mvc, saml, spring-saml

We have a Spring MVC application hosted in Google App Engine. Now it has been integrated with Single Sign On using Spring-SAML Extension. After successful login, we are able to receive SAML response from idp. Now i have to capture the URL parameters passed by my initial URL.

Initial URL: (GET Request)

http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample/download?filename=Culture%20Close-Up&Type=Word&order=1&name=jack&city=Seatle

invokes idp -> login

Response from idp after successful login  (POST)

http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/SSO

I am able to receive the response, but the initial parameter values passed in
(eg:name=jack) is not receivable. How to preserve the parameter values.

Thanks.